# How to make it so it only respond if its exact (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making it so if I type @Wide#9256 it will respond

here is my code:

```
if (message.mentions.members.first() !== undefined) {

    if (message.mentions.members.first().id === bot.user.id) { 

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Prefix")
        .setDescription('My Prefix is "!"')
        .setFooter('Type !help for more information')
        .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        message.channel.send(embed)
  
   
  
    }
  
   }
```

But in this code it also respond if I said like "Hey @Wide#9256 h", I want it to respond if its only "@Wide#9256"  and nothing else.

I tried

```
if (message.content === message.mentions.members.first().id === bot.user.id)
```

Does not work, thank you in advance

Comment: Couldn't you directly compare to bot.user.id without the intermediate comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you'll just have to directly compare the message content to the raw mention format (`<@ID>`)

```js
// this leaves no spaces for anything before or after the mention
if (message.content === bot.user.toString()) { // generates mention format
  // ...
};
```

Comment: It now does not work somehow, it worked a week ago now it does not

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected Code:**

```js
    if(message.mentions.members.first() && message.content.split(' ').length === 1) {
        // Your code here
    }
```

**How it works:**

The `message.content.split(' ')` returns an array of all the parts of the message as separate elements, separated by `' '`. For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: What about `'@Person#0000test'`